# Number of functions - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem with a question in combinatorics even though it seems like a simple one unfortunately I am still having trouble to see the solution...

The question is:

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$
Find the number of functions $f: A \rightarrow A$ such that $\{1,2,3,4\} \subseteq f[A]$

I tried to solve it with Inclusion-exclusion principle:

We will denote $Ai$ = {Group of all functions where i isn't in the image of $f[A]$}

Then I looked for of $A1^\mathsf{c} \cap A2^\mathsf{c} \cap A3^\mathsf{c} \cap A4^\mathsf{c}$
which is by De-Morgan : $(A1 \cup A2 \cup A3 \cup A4)^\mathsf{c}$ and then I looked for $U - A1 \cup A2 \cup A3 \cup A4$

Calculations:
$U = 6^6$

$|A1| = |A2| = |A3| = |A4| = 6^5$

$|Ai \cap Aj| = 6^4$

$|Ai \cap Aj \cap Ak| = 6^3$

$|Ai \cap Aj \cap Ak \cap At| = 6^2$

$|U - A1 \cup A2 \cup A3 \cup A4| = 6^6 - {4 \choose 1}6^5 + {4 \choose 2}6^4 - {4 \choose 3} 6^3 + {4 \choose 4}6^2 = 22,500$

Then used inclusion-exclusion 'formula' to solve it.
But it seems to give me the wrong answer (Correct answer is 5880)

I'll appreciate any help, Thanks !

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you tell us what you've tried, and where you had trouble.

Comment: I've tried inclusion exclusion but it seems to give me the wrong answer (the answer for this question should be 5880 functions.)

Comment: Could you include your attempt in the question, so that we were able to find the source of the error?

Comment: $5880$ is correct.  I used inclusion-exclusion.  I echo @user's comment.  It will be more help to you if we find your mistake than just show you a correct calculation.

Comment: I just added it, but I didn't write the calculations that I did explicitly, because maybe the problem is with the way I did it and not with the calculations, I'll appreciate if you can review what I did.

Comment: Everything in your post so far is correct, so what went wrong must be in the calculations. Can you write those in your post? I agree it will be more instructive if we show you what went wrong instead of giving you the answer.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks Mike,  I added the calculations

Comment: You have one mistake (repeated several times)! $|A_1|\neq 6^5$. What should it actually be?

Comment: Oh silly me ! the problem found after almost 2 hours, Thanks alot Mike !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistake is the cardinality $|A_i|$. For example $A_1$ maps a set of 6 elements onto the set of 5 elements, therefore the number is $5^6$ not $6^5$. The same story is with other cardinalities.