# Combinatorics - Number of functions with a restriction on the image- combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I have tried to solve this question directly and using the inclusion-exclusion principle, but got two different answers.

I suspect the the direct solution isn't right, but I can't seem to find the mistake.

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
Find the number of functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ such that $\{1,2,3\} \subseteq f[A]$

Solving directly, there are ${4 \choose 3}$ options for choosing 3 different pre images for  $\{1,2,3\}$ and $3!$ options to choose the images of the chosen 3 pre images. Finally, there are 5 options for the image of the fourth element in $A$.
So I get ${4 \choose 3}\ 3!\ 5=120$.

With inclusion-exclusion principle (like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041182/number-of-functions-combinatorics)), I got 84.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first, $(1,2,3,4) \rightarrow (1,2,3,1)$ is counted twice: once as $(1,2,3) \rightarrow (1,2,3)$ and $4 \rightarrow 1$ and once as $(4,2,3) \rightarrow (1,2,3)$ and $1 \rightarrow 1$.  Inclusion-exclusion will correctly only count this once.

A correct direct solution breaks this into two parts:

1. the solution set is $\{1,2,3,x\}$ where $x$ is a number that doesn't have a requirement.  This is $4!\cdot2 = 48$ possible functions.
2. the solution multiset is $\{a,b,c,c\}$ where $a,b,c$ are $1,2,3$ in some order.  This has $\frac{4!}{1!1!2!2!}\cdot3! = 36$ possible functions.

Put together this is $48+36=84$ total functions.